# SHL with 0 operand

Tags: assembly, x86

in the snippet below of x86 assembly code that was produced by Visual Studio 2017, I see the instruction

```
shl         eax,0
```

What is the purpose of this instruction, as It should act as NOP as I understand it.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
011C1340  push        ebp  
011C1341  mov         ebp,esp  
011C1343  push        ecx  
    int a;
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
011C1344  mov         eax,4  
011C1349  shl         eax,0  
011C134C  mov         ecx,dword ptr [argv]  
011C134F  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+eax]
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an unoptimized version of the array access calculation. When optimization is not enabled, you may see all kinds of redundant/useless calculations which are eliminated with optimization. The compiler probably did something like this:

```
delta = elemsize*index
elemsize = 4, index=1
delta = 4*1 -> 4*(1 shl 0) -> 4 shl 0
```

which was then faithfully reproduced by codegen in assembly.